Invalid request timestamp in slackeventsapi.server.SlackEventAdapterException
I'm trying to create my first slack bot that uses Flask as a server to generate responses to the messages in the bot's channel. Briefly, my steps were:

create a Slack app, create events subscriptions (mentions, messages etc), acquire all necessary keys
create an event subscription using ngrok tool that tunnels responses from my locally running Flask app to a public URL
code bot logic and put it into a Flask app

Everything was fine with ngrok but when I tried a production server I couldn't verify the request URL getting the message Your URL didn't respond with the value of the challenge parameter. After some reading I thought that maybe I need to implement the dedicated method that would return that parameter. This time I reduced the logic to a very simple implementation but I still get another error slackeventsapi.server.SlackEventAdapterException: Invalid request timestamp. Here is my implementation:
import os
from flask import Flask, request
from slackeventsapi import SlackEventAdapter
app = Flask(__name__)
slack_bot_user_id = os.getenv('SLACK_BOT_USER_ID')
slack_events_adapter = SlackEventAdapter(os.getenv('SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET'), '/slack/events', app)


@app.route('/slack/events', methods=['POST'])
def get_events():
    # print(request)
    return request.json['challenge']


@slack_events_adapter.on('message')
def handle_message(event_data):
    print(event_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8000, host='0.0.0.0')

I think I'm following something similar to the guideline from the slackeventsapi python package repository and in my understanding it is the following:

in line 6 I define an adapter that connects the Flask server app with the Slack app
in lines 9-13 I define a function that will return "challenge" flag as requested by the Events API
(lines 15-17 is a placeholder for the actual logic implementation; will be filled when app is verified successfully).

I try to test app with command
curl -X POST -d '{"challenge": "empty"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" 127.0.0.1:8000/slack/events
and get the error traceback never getting inside the get_events function:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rsuleimanov/Documents/llm_deeds/langchainenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/rsuleimanov/Documents/llm_deeds/langchainenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/rsuleimanov/Documents/llm_deeds/langchainenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/rsuleimanov/Documents/llm_deeds/langchainenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/Users/rsuleimanov/Documents/llm_deeds/langchainenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/slackeventsapi/server.py", line 94, in event
    self.emitter.emit('error', slack_exception)
  File "/Users/rsuleimanov/Documents/llm_deeds/langchainenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyee/base.py", line 211, in emit
    self._emit_handle_potential_error(event, args[0] if args else None)
  File "/Users/rsuleimanov/Documents/llm_deeds/langchainenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyee/base.py", line 169, in _emit_handle_potential_error
    raise error
slackeventsapi.server.SlackEventAdapterException: Invalid request timestamp

What am I missing and what could the solution look like?
UPD: I could make a workaround passing the header like -H "X-Slack-Request-Timestamp: 1717762997" but then stumbling into an error Invalid request signature (which follows that logic), which I think I can resolve but still I'm sure that's not the way it should be handled. So the main question arises: how do I pass slack events verification?

If you are using slackeventsapi python package along with ngrok, then you don't need to add following piece of code-
@app.route('/slack/events', methods=['POST'])
def get_events():
  # print(request)
  return request.json['challenge']

You app should work fine without above piece of code.
I have a similar app in python flask used with ngrok.
